# Google Spreadsheet User permission with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am not able to replicate **the result** of these actions (see pictures) WITH GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT CODE.

Here are the actions:

Open a SpreadSheet with Google Spreadsheets

Right click -> Protect Range...

Click on this

[image]

Then click on this

[image]

And

[image]

I had **NO** success by trying this code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.addEditor('theEmailThatIWantToEnabled@email.com');
```

Comment: Please refer to GAS documentation. There's no "addEditor()" method present in the SpreadsheetApp class. Spreadsheet class does have it, but calling it will add editors globally whereas your intention is to have editors added to a range. You must call 'addEditor()' method on the instance of Protection class. More info with examples here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: Thank you Anton, 
my problem is the opposite: the SpreadSheet is completely protected except for 17 ranges that are "public". 

So I have not to protect a specific range but my aim is - for a specific email address - is to remove all the protections. 

Thank you for your suggestion, I am investigating on 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);

Comment: Problem solved thank you Anton for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution of this problem.

In my specific case the permissions were **"by sheets"** and **NOT  "by ranges"**.

So here a small working code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      protections[i].addEditor('theEmailYouWantEnabled@email.com');      
    }
```